# Android unit test права на взаимодействие с usb

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, тестирование, android-permissions

Мне нужно написать тест, который создавал бы файл на usb устройстве и проверял его наличие (к примеру). Но для взаимодействия с usb устройством необходимо получить права на [взаимодействие](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#permission-d).

Как я могу получить право на взаимодействие с usb в моих юнит тестах?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путем использования [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator).